# 5 GHZ connections not appearing in Wifi list

Tags: networking, drivers, kde

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE plasma. I want to connect to a 5 Ghz Wifi network, but it won't show up in the list of available networks. My Windows laptop can connect from the same spot just fine.

output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: 90:e8:68:7b:3d:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ce driverversion=6.5.0-26-generic latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
       resources: irq:123 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc600000-fc60ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: enp10s0
       version: 15
       serial: 58:11:22:b2:70:c3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.052.01-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.68.62 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:35 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc504000-fc504fff memory:fc500000-fc503fff
```

I tried installing [this driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) for my motherboard's PCIe network adapter, but it didn't help.

I also tried booting into another drive (also with Ubuntu) and it still didn't show up. Running `nmcli dev wifi` doesnt work either.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Could it be your system isn't able to make a 5 Ghz Wifi connection? There are some systems that can only utilize a lower speed connection.

Comment: No, I built this PC last year with relatively new parts, and the motherboard I used supports 5ghz (ASUS prime b550m-a)